# Nitpicking a Multiverse

Tags: alternate-worlds, universe

Let's say that there was a god attempting to create a multiverse to the specifications of a certain sci-fi horror cartoon ( [rick and morty](http://www.adultswim/videos/rick-and-morty/) ) , but just the basic outlines.

Which competing scientific theories would this god have to pick and choose to implement to create a multiverse that

- covers multiple timelines
- contains dimensions

Any and all help is appreciated, Thanks

Comment: I'm tempted to say that god should put the science book down and pull out his or her books on philosophy...

Comment: While this is a fantastic question, I'm not sure that it is at all possible to answer, especially in this forum.

Comment: Wow. This looks so broad that I almost can't see from one end to the other. Could you narrow it down some, and perhaps describe in the question itself exactly what you are looking for? While "fan fiction" questions aren't explicitly off topic as such, they do need to stand on their own in the same way as any other question on the site. It's often better to ask multiple questions that each cater to some aspect, rather than to try to bring it all into a single question; the odds that someone has the knowledge to offer an authoritative answer grows as the answer space narrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, perhaps a universe like ours.

I preface this answer by saying that I am not a physicist and that a lot of it will be educated (as possible) conjecture using the philosophies of the phenomena involved.

[Max Tegmark's four levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse#Max_Tegmark.27s_four_levels) of the multiverse describes a taxonomy of multiverses predicated upon various different disciplines within quantum mechanics, cosmology, and physics.

- **Level I** - In an infinite ergodic universe, there are an infinite amount of hubble volumes (spherical regions where the boundaries are receding greater than the speed of light.)
- **Level II** - Describes a multiverse that is expanding and developing little pocket Level I multiverses and hubble volumes, which include ones that have Big Bangs and Big Crunches.
- **Level III** - Describes a set of universes by the many-worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics where each resides in another branch of n-dimensional Hilbert space.

Second, you have the Poincaré recurrence theorem, which states that certain systems will, given sufficient time, return to an initial state. This allows you to travel to a point in time (I use travel loosely here, in the vein of Carl Sagan's [spaceship of the imagination)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmos:_A_Personal_Voyage) for any separate universe that satisfies the requirements of undergoing temporal repetition of this sort.

In [Don Page's paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9411193.pdf) *Information Loss In Black Holes And/Or Conscious Beings* he describes the recurrence time for a volume of our own universe as follows:

> For a black hole containing the mass within the presently visible region of our universe, it should be of the order of 
>   $ 10^{10^{10^{10^{2.8}}}}$ Planck time, millenia, or whatever.<sup>1</sup>

...

With infinite time and infinite space, you satisfy all the timelines and dimensional requirements. As for coming from a single universe, this goes into a bit of philosophy and semantics. If universes exist in singularities or from quantum phenomena within our universe, is our universe a universe or multiverse? Someone else can state more on that since I don't believe I can say objectively.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>"Whatever" is used here because the timescales required for these phenomena to occur are ungodly massive, far bigger than Googol or even a Googolplex and render the differences between Planck times and yottaseconds meaningless.</sub>

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I needed to know , thank you :)